# Why is the decoding of my JSON response not working in my Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a AuthController where I register the user and also log in the user. When the user is registered, I automatically log the user in by calling the login method. The login method returns a JSON object that looks like this

```
"meta": {
    "headers": {},
    "original": {
        "success": true,
        "token": "token is here"
    },
    "exception": null
}
```

How do I extract token from that JSON object that I get from `$this->login($request)`? Because right now $token returns Null.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $token = null;

    if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
        ], 401);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'token' => $token,
    ]);
}

public function register(RegistrationFormRequest $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->user_name = $request->user_name;
    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->role_id = 7;
    $user->subscription_plan_id = 1;
    $user->save();

    $token = json_decode($this->login($request), TRUE)['token'];

    return response()->json([
        'success'   =>  true,
        'data'      =>  $user,
        'meta'      =>  $token,
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: what does `dd(json_decode($this->login($request), TRUE))` output?

Comment: it returns a giant piece of javascript that I looked at via the preview in postman and it says null.

Comment: so was the `token` there in the object? or was the whole object null?

Comment: The whole object is null. The only way I ever see the token is when I var_dump ($this->login($request)) or return $this->login($request)  as json or in another json object.